# Run GitHub Action dynamically for each module in a repository

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

My repo has a following structure:

```
.
├── module1
├── module2
└── module3
```

I want to execute a predefined action (like [github.com/golangci/golangci-lint-action](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint-action)) for each module without copy-paste.

Ideally I would not like to list module names in `*.yml` files. If this is not possible, then I would like to specify the list only once so that I can reuse it in different workflows

Is it possible using any GitHub Actions features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matrix` to achieve this. Below example would be helpful for you

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        directory: [module1, module2, module3]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: '^1.13.1'
    - name: golangci-lint
      uses: golangci/golangci-lint-action@v2
      with:
          version: v1.29
          working-directory: ${{ matrix.directory }}
```

Comment: Yes but a matrix build can generate a max of 256 new jobs. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-build-matrix-for-your-jobs#:~:text=A%20job%20matrix%20can%20generate%20a%20maximum%20of%20256%20jobs%20per%20workflow%20run.%20This%20limit%20also%20applies%20to%20self%2Dhosted%20runners.